# How can I convert UTC time to other timezone by using timezone offset(-11:00)

Tags: php, timezone, timezone-offset

How can I convert UTC time to another timezone by using timezone offset (-11:00) using PHP? I have tried below but it's not working.

```
$utc_offset = '-11:00';
$dt = new DateTime(NULL, new DateTimeZone("$utc_offset"));
echo $date_echo = $dt->format('n/j/Y');
echo $time_echo = $dt->format('h:i A');
```

Can you please help me to find the proper solution?

Comment: I have mention php in my title, you may check it.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I missed that. People will first of all expect to find a php tag, next that it’s mentioned in the body text. Next for you, you may want to edit the question and specify in which way your code is not working: which incorrect result or which error message you are getting?